# Why does ninject's constructorScorer rate constructors which have unresolvable params?

Tags: ninject

Given some simple classes and interfaces...

```
public interface IClass1 { }; public class Class1 : IClass1 { }
public interface IClass2 { }; public class Class2 : IClass2 { }
```

... this injectable code ...

```
public class Class3
{
    public Class3(IClass1 class1, IClass2 class2)
    {
    }
    public Class3(IClass1 class1)
    {
    }
}
```

... and this setup ...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IClass1>().To<Class1>();

        var instance = kernel.Get<IClass1>();
    }
```

Ninject will crash declaring that it can't find a binding for IClass2.

On the one had this is understandable, because it doesn't have a binding for IClass2.

However it does have access to a constructor which does not require such a binding.

After some investigation, we have discovered that both of these constructors have the same 'score' because they both have the same number of resolvable parameters.

Ninject appears to treat them as equally valid. It picks the constructor which requires an IClass2 parameter because it is listed first within the code.

So if I reverse the order of these constructors thus...

```
public class Class3
{
    public Class3(IClass1 class1)
    {
    }
    public Class3(IClass1 class1, IClass2 class2)
    {
    }
}
```

... everything works.

My question is therefore....

**Why is the constructor (the one requiring an IClass2 parameter) ever considered a valid contender when it has unresolvable parameters?**

Comment: The question is: why do you have application components that have multiple constructors? Such class [should only have one](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: An interesting point. I will have to think a while on that one. For the moment the answer to your question is... "Legacy reasons which may no longer apply" :)

Comment: But TBH, I think this behavior is a bit weird. You would expect Ninject to select the constructor with most parameters from the list of constructors that only contains resolvable parameters.

Comment: if you are expecting a modern system to use legacy components, use an anti-corruption layer to isolate weird rules like this